# Function inside Where-Object clause

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find AD users by name and surname but with converted **non-english diacritics** to english signs

Ex. convert `Ł` to `L` etc.

So I wrote:

```psh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties GivenName, Surname | Where-Object {
  [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes($_.GivenName)) -eq $name
}
```

It's working fine, but I am getting an error:

> Exception calling "GetBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Array cannot be null."

Does Powershell not like function inside where clause?

Comment: Are all users have `GivenName` not null?

Comment: @PetSerAl No, because its still return a valid result (1 user in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an AD user doesn't have a set `GivenName` attribute, or if you forgot to retrieve it by specifying `-Properties GivenName` in your AD cmdlet call, `$_.GivenName` will evaluate to `$null`.

[`[Encoding]::GetBytes()` has a number of overloads:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
byte[] GetBytes(char[] chars)
byte[] GetBytes(char[] chars, int index, int count)
byte[] GetBytes(string s)
```

When you pass a `$null` value, the .NET runtime cannot figure out whether `$null` represents an empty string, and chooses the overload that takes a `char[]` instead, resulting in the `Array cannot be null` error.

Enclose `$_.GivenName` in double quotes, to force it to be recognized as a string, eliminating any ambiguity:

```
[Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes("{0}" -f $_.GivenName))
# or 
[Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes("$($_.GivenName)"))
```

This way, if `$_.GivenName` evaluates to `$null`, you'll just be passing an empty string to `GetBytes()`, which is perfectly valid

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Don't know how to thank you! Work perfectly